# Biological data source of trees

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, trees

I need some biological data for many types of trees, but I can not find good source of this on internet.
Where can I find following type of biological data of any tree:

- Biological Profile
- Taxonomy
- Distribution
- Cultivation
- Edible Medicinal Parts
- Phenology

Comment: Wikipedia: [Vascular Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vascular_plant)

Comment: All trees are either [gymosperms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnosperm) or [angiosperms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowering_plant)

Comment: Wikipedia: [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree)

Comment: Wikipedia: [Medicinal plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medicinal_plants)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ecological Data Wiki search for [Woody Plants](https://ecologicaldata.org/search?f[0]=taxonomy_vocabulary_2%253Aname%3AWoody%20Plants) is a good start for some nice datasets. There is also the [USDA Plants Database](http://plants.usda.gov/) which has information for every plant in the U.S. Woody species are well represented with lots of species specific info. These can be downloaded handily with an [R package](https://github.com/ropensci/rusda).

Looking for occurrences? Put the species name into [GBIF](http://www.gbif.org/) to get historical records of where and when a species was found. This has an [R package](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/) as well.

Want distribution maps for all trees in North America? Someone has done that for you [here](http://gec.cr.usgs.gov/data/little/).

Phenology? [The National Phenology Network](https://www.usanpn.org/).

Edibility? I've never come across a specific data source for this. But the best reference I've used is the [Handbook of Edible and Poisonous Plants of Western North America](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615275168). It's an amazing book with years of research put into it. It does not have any pictures nor a key to identify plants, but it does have information on pretty much every plant in the Western U.S. at least at the genus level.